# C++: How to read MySql data efficiently with libmysqld?

Tags: c++, mysql

I am using `mysql_query` + `mysql_store_result` + `mysql_fetch_row` to iterate over the fetched data.

The problem is that the latter returns an array of strings, even if all the data is numeric. So, I reckon, there is some kind of a numeric-to-string conversion going on when I fetch the records.

Is it possible to fetch the binary data directly? Like a binary record blob and let me to extract the column values from there?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I would like to clarify myself. I am not looking for ways to efficiently convert strings to numerics. I am looking for efficient ways to read my numeric data from MySql tables using the MySql C API as defined here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-functions.html. I am trying to imply here that my knowledge of this API leaves much place for improvement and so I am wondering whether the API provides more efficient ways to read the data.

Comment: mysql protocol and output API is textual, so this way or other you'll need to convert a string to a number.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you using a pre-built library like [CppDB](http://art-blog.no-ip.info/sql/cppdb/).

Its a light library providing features of parameterized inputs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not knowledgeable about MySQL, but you could check out [`strtol`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) for conversion.